# Styled radio buttons don't deselect when form is reset

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have 3 styled radio buttons:

```
<div class="col-md-12 form-group">
<label for="car-rental-pickup-location" class="mb-2">Pickup Location<small class="text-danger">*</small></label><br>
<div class="btn-group my-tab btn-group-toggle nav" data-toggle="buttons">
    <a href="#tab-pickup" class=" btn btn-outline-secondary flex-fill pudo" data-toggle="tab">
        <input type="radio" name="car-rental-pickup-location" id="car-rental-pickup-location-la" value="la" required onfocus="dateCheck();">Los Angeles
    </a>
    <a href="#tab-pickup" class="btn btn-outline-secondary flex-fill pudo" data-toggle="tab">
        <input type="radio" name="car-rental-pickup-location" id="car-rental-pickup-location-sf" value="sf" onfocus="dateCheck();">San Francisco
    </a>
    <a href="#tab-pickup" class="btn btn-outline-secondary flex-fill pudo" data-toggle="tab">
        <input type="radio" name="car-rental-pickup-location" id="car-rental-pickup-location-oc" value="oc" onfocus="dateCheck();">Orange County
    </a>
</div>

</div>
```

Screen shot of what it looks like:

[image]

When I reset the form or use javascript to check a different radio button, they don't update. How can I update these radio buttons?

Here it is running:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="col-md-12 form-group">
<label for="car-rental-pickup-location" class="mb-2">Pickup Location<small class="text-danger">*</small></label><br>
<div class="btn-group my-tab btn-group-toggle nav" data-toggle="buttons">
    <a href="#tab-pickup" class=" btn btn-outline-secondary flex-fill pudo" data-toggle="tab">
        <input type="radio" name="car-rental-pickup-location" id="car-rental-pickup-location-la" value="la" required onfocus="dateCheck();">Los Angeles
    </a>
    <a href="#tab-pickup" class="btn btn-outline-secondary flex-fill pudo" data-toggle="tab">
        <input type="radio" name="car-rental-pickup-location" id="car-rental-pickup-location-sf" value="sf" onfocus="dateCheck();">San Francisco
    </a>
    <a href="#tab-pickup" class="btn btn-outline-secondary flex-fill pudo" data-toggle="tab">
        <input type="radio" name="car-rental-pickup-location" id="car-rental-pickup-location-oc" value="oc" onfocus="dateCheck();">Orange County
    </a>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: _"When I reset the form or use javascript to check a different radio button"_ Please update your question to include that. We need a [mcve]

Comment: The problem is this is from a template, so there's a lot...

Comment: You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to include enough code for us to see what your code does. Likely, you need to reinitialize your component after the reset.

Comment: I just added the code, and it is functioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly; You need to actually go make sure they're unchecked, submitting a form or whatever doesn't magically do it for you. Hope this helps, cheers!

Addendum: After OP specified issue, the culprit is the anchor tag `parentNode` retaining its `active` css class so visually it still looks as though one in the group is selected. A remedy would be the following;

```js
resetGroup = (groupName) => {
  const group = document.getElementsByName(groupName);
  
  group.forEach(function(el) {
    el.checked = false;
    
    if (el.parentNode.classList.contains('active')) {
      el.parentNode.classList.remove('active');
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="col-md-12 form-group">
<label for="car-rental-pickup-location" class="mb-2">Pickup Location<small class="text-danger">*</small></label><br>
<div class="btn-group my-tab btn-group-toggle nav" data-toggle="buttons">
    <a href="#tab-pickup" class=" btn btn-outline-secondary flex-fill pudo" data-toggle="tab">
        <input type="radio" name="car-rental-pickup-location" id="car-rental-pickup-location-la" value="la" required>Los Angeles
    </a>
    <a href="#tab-pickup" class="btn btn-outline-secondary flex-fill pudo" data-toggle="tab">
        <input type="radio" name="car-rental-pickup-location" id="car-rental-pickup-location-sf" value="sf">San Francisco
    </a>
    <a href="#tab-pickup" class="btn btn-outline-secondary flex-fill pudo" data-toggle="tab">
        <input type="radio" name="car-rental-pickup-location" id="car-rental-pickup-location-oc" value="oc">Orange County
    </a>
</div>

</div>
<button onclick="resetGroup('car-rental-pickup-location')">Reset Group</button>
```

Comment: Try that with the above formatting, it doesn't work.

Comment: @tony oh, you just want the visual to return to default also. See updated answer. Oh and removed your onfocus event since the console errors were annoying for the example. Cheers